# Can one adjust GCS bucket lifecycle policies via Terraform AFTER bucket creation?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, terraform

I'm trying to set GCS bucket lifecycle policies via Terraform.
As far as I can tell, the [`google_storage_bucket`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/storage_bucket.html) resource only allows me to CREATE buckets; and not update existing ones. Trying to run a `google_storage_bucket` on an existing bucket raises a [409](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409).

The other storage-related resources do not seem to affect lifecycle policies.

So is it possible to adjust policies on existing buckets via Terraform, or should I switch to gsutil or something else?

Comment: Btw there is a feature request for this on the Terraform GitHub:
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/2481

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `import` your bucket to the terraform state before you can change the lifecycle.

1. Specify your bucket in something like `my-bucket.tf`
2. Import your bucket: `terraform import google_storage_bucket.my-bucket my-project/my-bucket`
3. If you have specified [lifecycle rules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/storage_bucket.html#lifecycle_rule) then you can just apply it: `terraform apply -target=google_storage_bucket.my-bucket`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Terraform does not have a Google Storage resource to update GCS bucket lifecycle 
[image]

You can update it via the [UI, gsutil or REST API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managing-lifecycles).

Comment: [Lifecycle rules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/storage_bucket.html#lifecycle_rule) can be used now for the `google_storage_bucket` resource.

Answer (score -1):

In Terraform once a bucket has been created, its location can't be changed, use the GCP Console to edit, I add the documentation for buckets.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions